# Magento module installation, manual or through Connect Manager?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

What is the preferred approach when installing modules into Magento?
Automatic through the Magento Connect Manager or manually by uploading the module to the server?
The reason I'm asking is that I've heard lots of conflicting stories concerning both approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would always suggest going through Magento Commerce but its not available for all extensions. They have to be approved by Magento before they are listed in the store.

But keep in mind, just because it was approved, it doesn't mean its tested or safe.

You can install manually, just do it via FTP so you can see if it replaces any files. If the module tries to replace any files (and you didnt previously install the extension) then I would not use that module. A module should never replace core files, just over ride them so just watch for that.

But either way is safe and fine in general. But it doesnt mean if its done one way there wont be problems. I wouldnt say either is more safe.

Comment: I should also point out the reason I would suggest doing it through Magento Commerce. Its just easier because its like two clicks VS downloading, unpacking, and uploading. Its something you can do from anywhere without needing FTP, just your Magento Admin login.

Comment: Great, thanks for the elaborative answer. Assuming I'd go the manual route, what about `package.xml`. Should it be uploaded together with everything else and placed in the root? It would seem it'd get overwritten by any additional extension.

Comment: The package.xml is an extension blueprint. If you see that, chances are that modules is available on Connect because its generated when you try to package an extension for connect.

But it does not replace the other package.xml - its used to install the extension when using something like SSH.

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself this:

> "Would I upload code to my *eCommerce application server* - sight unseen - and allow it to execute arbitrary code with *full write access* to the application database?"

The answer to that question is the *exact* same answer to the question you are asking. While there is slight curation of code on Connect, I cannot imagine anyone other than a non-technical store owner being able to justify admin-panel-based downloads as viable.

Always, always, always do a code review and a load test.

In addition to being able to download via CLI, there are a few sites out there which allow to direct download the free extensions from Connect. http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php is one of them.

Comment: Agree fully on your points on code reliabilty and security. It was a major reason why I had to ask this question. Personally I would prefer a package manager like pip or apt to manage all extensions but this is Magento/PHP-land where things are a bit different.